# Transfer money from Travel Card issued in India to an Indian bank account

Tags: india, money-transfer

My Travel card is loaded in USD and issued in India. Currently I am out of India and want to transfer the USD from travel card to my Indian bank account.

I almost tried all money transfer sites like Ria, Xoom, TransFast but all sites require a credit card issued in US for transferring USD. Is there a work around or way to transfer this dollars to Indian bank account through some websites or services like prepaid wallets/gift cards?

I didn't try PayPal since it charges huge fees.

Comment: Read the terms by your Travel Card issuer. Travel Card cannot be used to transfer USD to an Indian Bank Account. You have to spend outside India and if there is a balance you have to request the card issuers in writing for a refund.

Comment: yes  i understand...but i want to transfer the USd to indian bank account since the salary is credited in USD in travel card..

Comment: Salaries should not be credited on "Travel Card"

Comment: but it is credited to me there...is there a option to transfer through any means.pls help

Comment: I am also facing same problem. There is no way to transfer Money from USD travel Card to your Indian Account. Just Withdraw money from ATM and send it thru Western Union/Money-gram. But it will cost you lot. ATM Charges, VISA/Master Card Fee, Western Union Charges etc. If you found something then let me know..

Answer (score 1):

Read the terms by your Travel Card issuer. Travel Card cannot be used to transfer USD to an Indian Bank Account. You have to spend outside India and if there is a balance you have to request the card issuers in writing for a refund

Salaries should not be credited on "Travel Card"